# Can't stop nginx service

Tags: nginx, systemd

We have nginx running (on port 8080) in systemd `CentOS 7.7` but are unable to stop it - there is no error it just keeps running or respawning.

We've tried `sudo systemctl stop` and `sudo systemctl disable` and even `kill` but it keeps running.

```
Nov 11 13:04:18 myhost systemd[1]: Started The Gateway - Nginx.
[myuser@myhost gateway]$ sudo systemctl stop gateway
[myuser@myhost gateway]$ sudo systemctl status gateway
gateway.service - The Gateway - Nginx
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gateway.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2019-11-11 13:04:18 CET; 6min ago
  Process: 20988 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20985 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20983 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /daten/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20988 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 1.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/gateway.service
           ├─20990 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf
           └─20991 nginx: worker process

Nov 11 13:04:18 myhost systemd[1]: Starting The Gateway - Nginx...
Nov 11 13:04:18 myhost node-gateway[20985]: nginx: the configuration file /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf syntax is ok
Nov 11 13:04:18 myhost node-gateway[20985]: nginx: configuration file /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf test is successful
Nov 11 13:04:18 myhost systemd[1]: Started The Gateway - Nginx.
```

### Disable and stop

```
[myuser@myhost gateway]$ sudo systemctl disable gateway
Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/gateway.service.
[myuser@myhost gateway]$ sudo systemctl stop gateway
```

### Still Running

```
[myuser@myhost gateway]$ sudo systemctl status gateway
gateway.service - The Gateway - Nginx
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gateway.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2019-11-11 13:04:18 CET; 6min ago
 Main PID: 20988 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gateway.service
           ├─20990 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf
           └─20991 nginx: worker process

Nov 11 13:04:18 myhost systemd[1]: Starting The Gateway - Nginx...
Nov 11 13:04:18 myhost node-gateway[20985]: nginx: the configuration file /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf syntax is ok
Nov 11 13:04:18 myhost node-gateway[20985]: nginx: configuration file /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf test is successful
Nov 11 13:04:18 myhost systemd[1]: Started The Gateway - Nginx.
```

```
[myuser@myhost gateway]$ ps -auxf | grep nginx
myuser    21846  0.0  0.0 112684   696 pts/0    S+   13:11   0:00  |           \_ grep --color=auto nginx
root      20990  0.0  0.0  59080  1388 ?        Ss   13:04   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf
nginx     20991  0.0  0.0  61272  2708 ?        S    13:04   0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
```

```
[myuser@myhost gateway]$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 8080
node       1313              root   20u  IPv4 429747      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:51580->127.0.0.1:8080 (ESTABLISHED)
node       1313              root   21u  IPv4 432203      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:51640->127.0.0.1:8080 (ESTABLISHED)
node       1316 serviceuser   19u  IPv4 332198      0t0  TCP 172.25.24.45:57328->172.25.24.20:8080 (ESTABLISHED)
node       1316 serviceuser   21u  IPv4 318233      0t0  TCP 172.25.24.45:57260->172.25.24.20:8080 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx     20990              root    6u  IPv4 430360      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
nginx     20991             nginx    3u  IPv4 430473      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080->127.0.0.1:51580 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx     20991             nginx    6u  IPv4 430360      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
nginx     20991             nginx   25u  IPv4 432204      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080->127.0.0.1:51640 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2019-11-11 13:04:18 CET; 6min ago
```

To me it looks inactive (=dead, stopped, whatever you like to call it)?

EDIT: It seems the process might still be hanging around:

```
root      20990  0.0  0.0  59080  1388 ?        Ss   13:04   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.con
```

You can try to kill it manually with the kill command, try SIGKILL if SIGTERM won't work

```
kill -SIGTERM <process id, 20990 in this case>
```

Comment: Excellent analysis and solution. I do wonder why it "hangs around"...

Comment: its more like a zombie processes which still not knows about that it is dead xD

Comment: But even without the zombies: when my service is running and enter `systemctl stop myservice` it does not stop - pid remains. When I do `kill -SIGTERM` it does stop. The service configuration has `KillSignal=SIGTERM`. What's up with that?